Multiple TMC2226 on the same PCB; how many capacitors?
I'm totally new in PCB design, especially design with SMD components. Please help me understand what I'm thinking wrong.
I'm thinking about placing 3 TMC2226 Silent stepper motor drivers on the same board along with ESP32 to control them.
According to the reference, each driver needs a couple of 0.1 μF and one 100 μF capacitors from 24 V to the ground.
I'm going to go with 4 layers: signal, ground, 24 V, signal, which renders all the capacitors for all ICs essentially in parallel from 24 V layer to the ground layer.
Can I replace at least three 100 μF capacitors with one 300 μF given that all 3 IC will be close to each other as much as possible?
Can I place all six 0.1 μF capacitors next to each other, instead of next to IC?
What does “near to the pin” (from the reference) mean exactly?

"near to the pin" is the "shortest way" between the power supply pins of IC.

For the 100uF capacitor you might well be ok with a single cap, but the 0.1u caps are there to deal with relatively high frequency changes in load and so you’re better off with separate capacitors.  Personally I’d use three 100u caps though - stick as closely as you can to the reference design unless there’s a good reason not to.

Thanks for your advice. With dedicated traces the concept of "near to the pin" is more or less clear to me. For the sake of simplification, if a dedicated layer is used, is it correct to suppose some kind of area of effect for capacitors that should cover the IC ?

Fatter tracks are generally better than skinny ones, and a plane is for most purposes a very fat track.  You’ll still want to place the capacitor so it has a short electrical path to the power pins, but power planes will give you the best  performance (which is what you want)

Any IC that produces sharp current transients for its loads is sinking and sourcing that current from the supplies, which produces voltage dips and peaks at its own supply pins, and is therefore a hazard to itself and other ICs connected to the same supplies.
The cause of those supply fluctuations is inductance in the traces and wiring around the large current loop between the power supply and the current sinking/sourcing IC, making it impossible for the supply to "keep up" with sudden changes in current demand. Voltage \$V\$ developed across inductance \$L\$ is proportional to rate of change of current \$I\$:
$$ V = L \frac{dI}{dt} $$
The larger the physical area of current loop from supply, through IC, to load and back to supply, the more inductance \$L\$ there is, and the bigger the dips and peaks in voltage as current demand changes.
The role of each capacitor is to provide a short term source of voltage (energy) for the IC very close by, forming a much smaller current loop area, with much lower inductance. "Near" to pins means just that. Connect the capacitors as physically close to the IC's supply pins as possible, to keep loop area to a minimum.
The ceramic (100nF or similar) decoupling capacitors are the most critical. These deal with the fastest current transients, but store very little energy, and cannot maintain supply potential difference at the supply pins for very long, under sustained current demand. However, they have very low ESR, and can deal with very large changes in current demand (many amperes) for very short periods (nanoseconds). These will be mounted closest to the IC supply pins.
Less critical are the (comparatively) high ESR electrolytic capacitors, whose role is to provide current over the longer term (microseconds), since they store much more energy. Even though their high ESR is a limiting factor, loop inductance is still the primary concern, and while they they can be installed further away, we are still talking millimeters, not centimeters. The goal is always to mitigate inductance in the larger supply-IC-supply loop.
Since stepper motor drivers are causes of significant short and mid-term current transients, you can't get away with poor decoupling. Remember that from the perspective of some IC, not only do you require fast-acting energy sources for your own load, you are also messing up the supply for everyone else nearby. While it might be tempting to have some bulk capacitance shared between three motor drivers, it's risky business. If you've tripled the distance between IC supply pins and the capacitance, you've likely more than tripled the inductance, and you can expect your mess to spread further out. I would not recommend that approach. The suggested use of two 100μF capacitors, instead of a single 220μF device is a clue that decoupling is critical.
I can't say if it would break the design, for you would need to observe the supply rail potentials under the worst expected load conditions to determine how bad things get. My gut feeling is that if you do this, you should also provide additional decoupling local to each driver, say 10μF ceramic. My gut feeling is also to do exactly as the datasheet says, a pair of individual 100μF for each driver, installed close to the supply pins.
As far as the ceramic 100nF capacitors are concerned, you should not install them all together, and further away from their ICs. These are critical, and must be installed really close to their respective driver IC supply pins. Again, clustering them together may work fine in your application, but doing so can only worsen reliability. So I recommend that you don't. If you have to, install them on the other side of the PCB, which makes the current loop even smaller still, as you see done with the dozens of decoupling capacitors for FPGAs.

Thank you for the comprehensive explanation. For now I set up the layout heavily peeking up at the reference. With your explanation now I know why it was done this way.
